# Name of road marking

Tags: word-choice

What is this striped road marking called?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**cheveron and diagonal/transverse (crosshatch) markings**

[image]

> **Cheveron and diagonal crosshatch markings define an area, within
> defined boundaries, over which vehicular traffic is discouraged**.
> Crosshatch lines should be sloped in the direction of the major flow
> of traffic. [US Army, Transportation Engineering Agency; "Crosshatch Markings"](https://www.sddc.army.mil/sites/TEA/Functions/SpecialAssistant/TrafficEngineeringBranch/BMTE/calcSigns/SignsAndMarkingsTurtorials/transverseMarkings/Pages/crosshatchMarkings.aspx)

When used for pedestrian crossings, they are also referred to as **zebra stripes**; however, your picture doesn't appear to show a pedestrian zone.

Answer (score 1):

**Hatched road markings**  ([DrivingTestTips.biz](https://www.drivingtesttips.biz/hatched-road-markings.html))
...or diagonal road markings can cause learner drivers a considerable amount of confusion. Hatched road markings are used to separate traffic lanes and to make it safer for the vehicles turning right.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that traffic lanes surround the hatched area. In that case, I'd call the no-go area an [island](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/island):

> something resembling an island especially in its isolated or surrounded position: such as . . . a usually raised area within a thoroughfare, parking lot, or driveway used especially to separate or direct traffic

Although an island is usually elevated, the term does apply here.